# Passing dynamic attribute to a view in a layout XML

Tags: android, android-layout

Let's say the layout XML for my activity has a view like this. The XML below has a hard-coded value for the attribute, but I want to pass value from activity when setting the content view.

```
<myView
     android:id = "@+id/myView
      ....
     app:myAttriute = "someMode"/>
```

The view reads that value in the constructor like the following and sets the initial mode.

```
constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
{
    val inflater = context?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.myView, this);

    var arr = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.myView);
    var mode = arr.getString(R.styleable.myAttribute);
```

Is it possible to set that attribute in the activity so that the value can be used in the view's constructor? It may sound weird, it causes some problems to change the mode after the view's constructor like this

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
val myView = findView...
myView.myAttribute = "someMode";
```

If possible, I wish I could pass the attribute to its constructor, somehow.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
//takes the view's ID and attribute name/value to be used while
//setting the content view (passed to myView's constructor)
hypotheticalMethod(R.id.myView, "myAttriute", "someMode");
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

Comment: Most likely you will have to focus on those "some problems" that occur when you change the mode dynamically after calling the constructor.. I don't think there is a way to instantiate an `AttributeSet` yourself.

Comment: isnt defining it in the XML pretty much the same as defining in a constructor? If the attribute itself has dependency in a service for example you will need to define it after setContentView

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If there is no other way, I will find a way to solve the "problems". I will not delete this post, so that people who wonder the same thing in the future will know that it is impossible.